# Android: EditText pushes the layout to the top

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a edit text in the bottom of my activity and when user click on the edit box it pushes the buttons and lables above it to futher top. How can I avoid this? when user clicks and types on the edit text it should not push the layout up.

```
<EditText android:gravity="top|left" android:hint="@string/description"
                android:id="@+id/editText1des" android:layout_below="@+id/buildbtn" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buildbtn"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buildbtn" android:layout_marginTop="30dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions" android:scrollHorizontally="true"></EditText>
```

Can someone please help me thanks.

full layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/homepgeaudiobtn"
    android:background="#E6E7E2">

    <RelativeLayout android:weightSum="1.0"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#cf1616" android:layout_height="50dp">

        <Button android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/butonn" android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_width="90dp" android:textColor="#FFF" android:text="@string/btnSubmitString" android:id="@+id/sendincidentbtn" android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="RDMS" android:textColor="#FFF" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:textSize="35dp"></TextView>

        <Button android:textColor="#FFF" android:layout_height="30dp" android:layout_width="90dp" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:id="@+id/backid" android:background="@drawable/back_button" android:text="@string/gobackString" android:layout_margin="10dp"></Button>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:weightSum="1.0"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#FFF" android:layout_height="65dp">

        <Button android:id="@+id/allimagebtn" android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:background="@drawable/cam_red" android:text="Images" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:paddingTop="2dp" android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_margin="2dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="bottom"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/button2video" android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:background="@drawable/vid_red" android:textColor="#FFF" android:text="Video Files" android:gravity="bottom" android:textSize="12dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingTop="2dp" android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/button3audio" android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:background="@drawable/aud_red" android:text="Audio Files" android:gravity="bottom" android:textSize="12dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingTop="2dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_margin="2dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_width="0px" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2993"
        android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"></LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000" android:textSize="20dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="Ipsum Lorem" android:paddingLeft="20dp"></TextView>

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView android:layout_height="0dp" android:text="TextView"
                android:id="@+id/allincidentimagecount" android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/allimagebtn" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/allimagebtn"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/allimagebtn"></TextView>
            <Button android:layout_below="@+id/allincidentimagecount"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/allincidentimagecount"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="@string/type"
                android:id="@+id/typebtn" android:layout_marginTop="5sp" android:background="@drawable/tab_top" android:layout_height="40dp" android:gravity="left|fill_vertical" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:textSize="20dp"></Button>
            <Button android:text="@string/location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/typebtn"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/typebtn" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/typebtn"
                android:id="@+id/locbtn" android:background="@drawable/tab_middle" android:layout_height="32dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:gravity="left|fill_vertical" android:textSize="20dp"></Button>
            <Button android:text="@string/building"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/locbtn"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/locbtn" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/locbtn"
                android:id="@+id/buildbtn" android:background="@drawable/tab_bottom" android:layout_height="43dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:gravity="left|fill_vertical" android:textSize="20dp"></Button>
            <EditText android:gravity="top|left" android:hint="@string/description"
                android:id="@+id/editText1des" android:layout_below="@+id/buildbtn" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buildbtn"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buildbtn" android:layout_marginTop="30dp" android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions" android:scrollHorizontally="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></EditText>


            <TextView android:layout_height="0dp" android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_below="@+id/button2video"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2video"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2video" android:id="@+id/videovounttxt99"></TextView>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/audiocounttxtx"
                android:layout_height="0dp" android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_below="@+id/button3audio"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3audio"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3audio"></TextView>   
        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/layout02"
        android:paddingTop="30dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="#000" android:gravity="center"></TextView>


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that you have used the same button id for the three attributes namely

```
android:layout_below="@+id/buildbtn" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buildbtn"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buildbtn"
```

wherein lies your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the EditView so far down the screen, that the keyboard will hide it, and you won't be able to see what you are writing? Are you sure you want to hide the EditText field from the user?

Are you using a scrollview?

Comment: no i'm not using scrollview, atleast is it possible for me to keep the header fixed and move the rest above??

Comment: header? I'm not sure what you want to do? Either give me some more code or take a screendump of your problem with the DDMS?